# AsmJit equivalent of mov eax,[ecx+0CC]

Tags: c++, c, assembly, asmjit

What is the asmjit equivalent of `mov eax,[ecx+0CC]`?

This is close: `c.mov_ptr(x86::eax, x86::ptr(x86::ecx, 0x0CC))`; but the arguments are wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: If _c_ is the compiler object. Do you have an assembler object like _a_? If so how about `a.mov(x86::eax, x86::ptr(x86::ecx, 0x0CC));`

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Yep, just using the assembler object seems to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

`a.mov(x86::eax, x86::ptr(x86::ecx, 0x0CC));`