# AsmJit how to get raw bytes

Tags: assembly, asmjit

How to encode the instruction like this **`mov eax, 0x00123456`**
and get **b8 56 34 12 00**?
I know how to encode but how to get the output in the buffer using AsmJit because encoding manually is not a good way to solve problem? It can be done more easily using AsmJit.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Have you tried writing the bytes to the buffer?

Comment: The asmjit documentation should show how to use it.  I'd expect you can pass it a string like `"mov eax, 0x00123456"` or whatever form it wants you to specify mnemonic and operands in.  It would write the 5-byte machine code into the output buffer you give it, and return the length.  I haven't used asmjit myself, but this seems like a "hello world" type of problem for asmjit.  That's all you're asking for, right?

Comment: Seems pretty similar to [AsmJit equivalent of mov eax,\[ecx+0CC\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35195420) but with a different source operand, and you want to know the length and read the buffer.

Comment: But how to get output. I know how to encode but getting output is the problem. I cant find function which provides me output data

Comment: Docs say it assembles into a `CodeBuffer` (https://asmjit.com/doc/structasmjit_1_1CodeBuffer.html), which as `uint8_t* data()` member function, and size and capacity.

Comment: AsmJit has an online documentation, which discusses how to get raw bytes:

https://asmjit.com/doc/group__asmjit__core.html

See `More About Environment` section.